# Why not use AppResources directly

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone

I'm writng a large localized Windows Phone 8 application. When I open a blank WP8 project. It generates AppResources.resx file and LocalizedStrings class.

LocalizedStrings class is used to hold a static AppResources field and a nonstatic accessor to that field. And in the resources of App.xaml LocalizedStrings is added as follows:

```
<local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectNS" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
```

and used in pages as:

```
Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

Instead of the default use, below solution also works:

In App.xaml:

```
<local:AppResources xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectNS.Resources" x:Key="AppResources"/>
```

In pages:

```
Text="{Binding ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource AppResources}}"
```

So why don't we use the below one? Because it has one less class(LocalizedStrings is not needed) and When we use localized strings in pages it is shorter (you don't need to write  "LocalizedResources.some_string" all time, just write "some_string")

Is there anything wrong with my solution that I can't see?

Comment: No if you do not want to have multiple languages?

Comment: Why would this prevent me from having multiple languages?

Comment: The localized string taps into the current culture and can then use the correct AppResources file. At least that is how I have learned it :)

Comment: Only code in LocalizedResources class is below. So I don't think it has anything to do with the current culture.

`private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();`
`public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }`

Comment: see this link they use exactly the localized string class to accomplish having different cultures. http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/localizing-a-windows-phone-app-step-by-step

Comment: The Geekchamp article does not explain why we have to do that. Anyways spending some tim on the project, I decided to try if the way I proposed works. An now I get XamlParseException (which is caused by the AppResources  has an internal constructor, it needed to be public for me) Sp I decided to do it the common way. Thanks for the comments